# How do you get the ouput of a keras model as a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

How do I get the output of a keras model as a numpy array? My code looks like this:

```
env = gym.make('Chess-v0')
obs = env.reset()
type(obs)

done = False

num_actions = len(env.legal_moves)

obs = chess.Board()

model = models.Sequential()

def dqn(board):
    
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(1,))

    layer1 = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu", input_shape=(1,))(inputs)
    layer2 = layers.Dense(512, activation="relu")(layer1)
    layer3 = layers.Dense(512, activation="relu")(layer2)
    
    layer4 = layers.Dense(512, activation="relu")(layer3)
    layer5 = layers.Dense(512, activation="relu")(layer4)
    
    layer6 = layers.Dense(1)(layer5)
    
    action = np.argmax(--->>> layer6_output <<<---)
    
    return keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=action)
```

so how do I get the output of layer6 as a numpy array?

Comment: try to read this: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer-of-a-keras-model-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf.tensor.eval to return np array you can read on docs [DOCS](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor).
and then you just add tf.tensor.eval in layer 6

Answer (score 0):

Once you have defined the model with something like `myModel=dqn(board)`, you can use `myModel.predict(x)` to get the output as a Numpy array.

If you are using Tensorflow as a backend with eager execution enabled you can just put `.numpy()` in your tensor.